# Python multiple lists elements compare

Tags: python, list, compare, element

I want to compare all lists elements and check if they are + or - 40(or the same) within the value of other elements.

For example: Value 400 in list1 to be compared with all elements in list2 & list3 if one of their elements is between 360 and 440.

```
list1 = [100,200,300,400,400]
list2 = [90,400,410,500,600]
list3 = [600,380,110,800,900]

output: 400,410,380
```

I've tried a double for loop but then its only checking one element in list1:

```
for x in list1:
  for xy in list2, list3:
   if x <= 400 <= xy:
    print "something"
```

But it never prints something.

I hope my explanation and example is good enough, if not please let me know what you're missing!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: So, where are you going to start? When you have written some code and if it doesn't work, post your non-working code and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = [100,200,300,400,400]
list2 = [90,400,410,500,600]
list3 = [600,380,110,800,900]
complist = [j for i in zip(list2, list3) for j in i]
myrange=40
for x in list1:
  for y in complist:
      if x-myrange <= y <= x+myrange:
          print('list1={}: complist={} is within range {}'.format(x, y, myrange))
```

I created a new list containing all the values you want to compare from `list2` and `list3`. I guess that the printing code I used is generic for Python3, so you might have to adapt this.

Comment: Downvoted... Accepted, then revoked... Please leave some comments at least.

Comment: Oh my bad, just tested your solutions and it works fine!
Thanks a lot!:-)